# Do energy levels ever appear at the peak of a cosine potential in higher dimensions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, spacetime-dimensions

I simulated a hyperspherically symmetric wavefunction for the case of $V=-\cos(r)$, in which $h=1$, and $m=1$ and the number of spatial dimensions is $4$.

I charted the integral of the square of the absolute value of the wavefunction multiplied by $r^3$

[image]

[image]

I find that in both charts the integral looks the same even though I used different initial values for the initial value for the derivative of the wavefunction in each.  Also the integral appears to be converging on a finite value.

Also the wavefunctions look the same no matter what initial value I choose for the derivative of the wavefunction

[image]

[image]

This indicates that the simulation is surprisingly resilient to having different initial values

Also this is what the square of the absolute value of the wavefunction multiplied by $r^3$ looks like

[image]

[image]

Also this is the energy and potential

[image]

Am I at or at, or if not at, near an Energy Level?

Comment: “Check-my-work” questions are out of bounds...

Comment: _"Also the wavefunctions look the same no matter what initial value I choose for the derivative of the wavefunction"_ — this is suspicious. The potential is non-singular at $r=0$ (where I suppose your initial condition is), so the wavefunction should be sensitive to the initial condition. _"Am I at or at, or if not at, near an Energy Level?"_ — try the [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) to locate the eigenvalues of your one-dimensional radial Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Ruslan I calculated the second derivative using the equation $\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\left(V\Psi-E\Psi\right)-\frac{(d-1)}{r}\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial{r^2}}$, with $d$ being the number of spatial dimensions, and set $d=4$.  It looks like close to $0$ a value for the derivative that isn't also close to $0$ causes the second derivative to have a large magnitude and the opposite sign from the derivative, causing the derivative to quickly get pushed to a value near $0$.  I also avoided starting at $r=0$ as that would have just resulted in an error message.

Comment: Well, that might be correct actually, since the second solution is singular, so the alternative derivative would be infinite. In fact, the correct boundary condition at such points is the _regularity_ condition. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/774332/64206) for more info on actual computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider $r\in[r_{\text{min}},r_{\text{max}}]=[10^{-5}, 30].$ This will be our domain for numerical computation of the solution your Schrödinger equation. The equation, as given in the comments to the OP, is

$$\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\left(V\Psi-E\Psi\right)-\frac{(d-1)}{r}\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial{r}}=\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial{r^2}},$$

where $d=4,$ $\hbar=\frac h{2\pi}=\frac1{2\pi},$ and $m=1$. Using the initial conditions $\Psi(r_{\text{max}})=0,$ $\Psi'(r_{\text{max}})=-1,$ we can solve the Cauchy problem in the given domain with varying values of $E$ around the supposed eigenvalue, $E=1.$ This yields the following result for $\Psi(r_{\text{min}})$:

[image: Ψ(rMin) vs E]

As you can see, the function at $r=10^{-5}$ is huge for most of the values of $E$ in the range $[0.999, 1.001]$, and only around $1.00019$ does it become much smaller. If we make $r_{\text{min}}$ smaller, the huge values will be even larger, while the value at the dip will remain almost the same. The dip itself doesn't move much. This dip is then the eigenvalue of our system (with the restricted domain).

Changing the domain to be closer to actually desired $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ doesn't change the estimated eigenvalue much, so we can be reasonably sure that your exact problem doesn't have an eigenvalue at $E=1$, instead having a bit larger one, $E\approx 1.00019.$

What we've done above is known as the [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) of locating eigenvalues in ODE problems.

Comment: Does a dip in $\Psi(r_{min})$ similar to the one shown always indicate an Eigenvector?  Also is it always more useful to have the initial value be $\Psi(r_{max})$ and the final value $\Psi(r_{min})$ than the other way around for the shooting method?

Comment: @AndersGustafson the dip corresponds to an eigenvalue _iff_ the solution for this value of $E$ satisfies the boundary conditions. We, using the truncated domain, only estimate the eigenvalue, since when the function doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions, it diverges at the singular endpoints.

Comment: @AndersGustafson The choice of where to set the initial condition in shooting method is mostly determined by convenience. It was more convenient for me to use the far point as the starting point, since I know exactly that for a homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition the derivative at that endpoint is nonzero. I don't know _a priori_ anything about the derivative at $r=0$.

Comment: I also tried approximating the eigenvalues for the hydrogen atom using the shooting method you gave, and found that it seemed that on one side of an eigenvalue the wavefunction blows up in the negative direction, and on the other side it blows up in the positive direction near $0$.  I found the same for the eigenvalue you mentioned for the cosine potential.  Is the curve you showed the absolute value of the wavefunction near the minimum value for $r$?

Comment: @AndersGustafson yes, it's the absolute value, since on logarithmic scale you can't show negative numbers. The general trend is indeed that the value of the function will change sign as you cross an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank You for the information!